# Not completing boot. Failing to mount the local file system

Tags: boot, filesystem

On boot I'm getting to the line

```
[OK] Setting kernel variables ... done
```

A few lines before that there is a failure

```
[....] Mounting local file system...[    14.601764] mmc0: missed completion of cmd 18 DMA (512/512 [1]/[1]) - ignoring it
[    14.914927] mmc0: DMA IRQ 6 ignored - results were reset
failed
```

The changes leading up to the this were that I installed upstart and then tried to reboot (`sudo reboot`). The reboot command didn't error, it also didn't do anything, no output to the screen like "Hey I'm about to reboot!" or whatever the normal message is. I tried the command a few more times, and then pulled the plug. I've been getting the above or simply a failure to load the file system ever since.

How can I fix this?

Output from fsck (3.9GB part, ext4):

```
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information

   66856 inodes used (28.14%)
      25 non-contiguous files (0.0%)
      93 non-contiguous directories (0.1%)
         # of inodes with ind/dind/tind blocks: 0/0/0
         Extent depth histogram: 51823/14
  386579 blocks used (40.76%)
       0 bad blocks
       1 large file

   46850 regular files
    4498 directories
      12 character device files
      25 block device files
       2 fifos
     594 links
   15460 symbolic links (14972 fast symbolic links)
       0 sockets
--------
   67441 files
```

59MB part, vfat:

```
Checking we can access the last sector of the filesystem
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkdosfs"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
      8192 bytes per cluster
        16 reserved sectors
First FAT starts at byte 8192 (sector 16)
         2 FATs, 16 bit entries
     16384 bytes per FAT (= 32 sectors)
Root directory starts at byte 40960 (sector 80)
       512 root directory entries
Data area starts at byte 57344 (sector 112)
      7161 data clusters (58662912 bytes)
63 sectors/track, 255 heads
         0 hidden sectors
    114688 sectors total
Reclaiming unconnected clusters.
/dev/sdd1: 11 files, 2109/7161 clusters
```

Comment: That error shouldn't be fatal. Is that the only one?

Comment: Sometimes I get `[FAIL] Mounting local filesystem...failed`

Comment: It sounds like there are I/O problems with the SD card. I would recommend running `fsck` on the partitions with the card plugged into another *nix machine firstly, otherwise, try another SD card.

Comment: @Munkeh I've added the fsck output. Not getting any further in the boot, sadly.

Comment: Just been looking through this thread: http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=5057&start=150 and it seems the error is non-critical. You can probably safely ignore it.

Comment: @Munkeh Thanks! Is there any way I can figure out why the boot isn't finishing?

Comment: That's an issue with `upstart`, which I'm not familiar with, sorry. I would revert back to `sysinit` or use `systemd` for a fix.

Comment: Check your SD card against [this list](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) to make sure it is supported.  I started out using one that was not and had similar issues, though it was long enough ago I don't remember the exact error

Comment: @AwesomeUser Nope. I bought a new SD card and started over.

Comment: @AwesomeUser what? That I don't have an answer? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @MattEllen Well I believe somehow the card got corrupted.  Just don't pull the plug on the pi, and shutdown properly.  I think there is a few other things that can keep a sd card from getting corrupted, but I don't know any others off the top of my head.  Try Googling it.

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that your file system is corrupted. You will need to re-install Raspbian.

Comment: A successful fsck belies this. I agree with with the comments above that the SD card was corrupted, or that the card was slightly incompatible with the current firmware.

Comment: Usually, reinstalling is the *last* option. Please don't suggest that someone do that unless other answers have been suggested and have failed.